# Is there a way to give CSS to all Placeholders in sencha touch application

Tags: css, sencha-touch-2.3

I am struggling to find a way to give CSS to all placeholders in my application,

I have tried the following:

```
.customField input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #2e4bc5;
}

.x-text-field input::webkit-input-placeholder{
color :#2e4bc5
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.customField .x-input-el::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #2e4bc5;
}
```